# These credentials do not match our records

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla User con lo siguiente:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('saldo');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Cuando creo la tabla tengo preparado un usuario que se introducira en la recien creada tabla en DatabaseSeeder.php:

```
User::create([
            'name' => 'Rigoberto Disousa',
            'email' => 'pajaritosami88@gmail.com',
            'password' => '1234567',
            'saldo' => 0,
        ]);
```

Creo la tabla e intento hacer login, pero me veo con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como lo arreglo?

Edito: He modificado así el valor del usuario:

```
User::create([
            'name' => 'Rigoberto Disousa',
            'email' => 'pajaritosami88@gmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('1234567'),
            'saldo' => 0,
        ]);
```

Y al hacer la migración queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el fallo persiste.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Utilizo para migración "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed".

Comment: no veo que estes hasheando la contraseña al introducirla

Comment: Pareciese obvio, pero, ¿has ejecutado el seeder?

Comment: ¿php artisan migrate:refresh --seed?

Comment: Parece que por ahora lo he solucionado. Parece que es que no ponia correctamente la contraseña. Aunque hay veces en las que juraria que puse bien la contraseña e igualmente falla. Por no hablar de que ya podria salir un mensaje de error más explicativo...